# Shorter shorthand than ternary for setting variable to itself

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean, logic

I am trying to check if a variable is empty and if it is then set another variable to one string and if it's not then set the other variable to the first variable. Right now I am using a ternary operator, but I was wondering if there is an even shorter way to do this because it is setting it to a variable used in the logic.

Here is my code:

```
$company_name = $project->company->name;
$this->project['company_name'] = !empty($company_name)
                                    ? $company_name
                                    : "Company";
```

Comment: only for single var or multiple vars? for multiple you can use function with ternary

Comment: I'll probably doing this for a few variables

Comment: I am not sure why you would want to shorten it even more. I prefer to write my code with clarity and readability in mind. Trying to shorten something that is already short seems unnecessary.

Comment: I agree eagle12, but if there was a better way to do this I wanted to know which is why I asked. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.3+ you can use [?:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1539210/1026641) but other than that no.

```
$this->project['company_name'] = $company_name ?: "Company";
```

Empty variables should evaluate to false and assign "Company".

Comment: 100% what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

try make a function for more variables pass values in it. you can check multiple variables using this. else i think no way to do check you to use and set other values same like (you are already using shorten)

```
$check = mycheck($check, 'mysting');

function mycheck($check, 'mysting') {
  $return = (!empty($check) ? $check : "mysting");
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question

Comment: "Right now I am using a ternary operator, but I was wondering **if there is an even shorter way to do this**"

Comment: This answer is the one that goes best with what I was looking to do. In response to bartek, I was wondering if I didn't have to write the ternary operation every time since it is similar logic each time.

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->project['company_name'] = !empty($project->company->name) 
                                  ?  $project->company->name
                                  : "Company";
```

Comment: <.< You just copied what he posted.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?

Comment: no, it isn't an exact copy.  And it would be easier to understand @banditpanda if you provided some type of explanation about why this is a more concise version of the same functionality in the quesion.

Comment: Answers should explains what they are doing and not be games of spot-the-difference.

Answer (score -2):

You can use in your function call variable=company. Then omit the ternary operator.

```
   function xyz ($company="company") {
       if ($this->project['company_name']) {
          $company=$this->project['company_name'] ;
         }
```

function even doesn't need return, depends on the usage.

Comment: Can you clarify this?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I don't even have enough points to downvote.

Comment: @Phpdna - why do you think this is better than the accepted answer? Overhead of a function call, and a function that doesn't even do anything. That's probably why it got downvoted

Comment: There is a function call anyway?