# Multiple conditional php with OR logical operator not returning false

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have a conditional statement in php, when I add an OR logical operator it doesn't work as intended, in the below example it returns the code that I am trying to prevent it doing.

Individually each statement works just not when they are together as I have them below. It seems inefficient to repeat the code for each condition.

`if (!is_sp_post_type('profile') || !is_category(array('previews','reviews')) || !is_single(array('previews','reviews'))) {
       //do stuff 
    };`

I have read this answer [Is there a short-circuit OR in PHP that returns the left-most value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539204/is-there-a-short-circuit-or-in-php-that-returns-the-left-most-value) but I'm still stuck

Comment: What logic do you actually expect? You want to "do stuff" if either of the primary tests fails? I mean if it is not type=>profile OR not category=> reviews OR not single=> reviews?

Comment: I want to do stuff provided it does not meet either of the primary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of the `AND` (`&&`) operator.

The `OR` operator just needs one true to execute the conditional, whereas the `AND` operator needs all statement to be true.

I'm not hundred percent sure what you are trying to achieve, but I would also suggest having a re-look at your `NOT` (`!`) operator and how it is used in your code

Comment: Do you assume a logical mistake by the OP? Better ask for clarification.

Comment: Do you actually know how the operators work? I don't assume as you are accusing me of and downvoted my answer because of your accusation, this **is** purely a logical problem. I don't need to get any clarification on this. This is not my first question on a subject like this regarding wordpress

Comment: You yourself say, you are not sure.. The OP talks about "inefficiencies to repeat the code for each condition", so it looks he actually wants the OR semantics.. but who knows (so i asked).

Comment: The `do stuff` code displays the date when a post was last updated. This function is applied to a template for many different pages (a single post template and an archive template). I'm trying to prevent this function from being displayed on just a few of those pages. `if (!is_sp_post_type('profile') || !is_category(array('previews','reviews')) || !is_single(array('previews','reviews')) {
     echo '<div class="sp-updated-on">Last updated ' . human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago</div>'; 
 };` As far as I understand, this requires an OR operator.

Comment: @fast It would be great if you can remove your downvote now. Please, next time, think before you just downvote an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was being silly, should have been using `&&`

`if (!is_sp_post_type('profile') && !in_category(array('previews','reviews')) && !is_single(array('previews','reviews'))) {
        //do stuff 
    }`

Thanks to [Pieter Goosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1908141/pieter-goosen) for pointing this out - he deleted his answer though so I cannot select it.

Comment: Great for posting and giving me some kind of credit. Appreciated. +1

Comment: Sure thing I've accepted your answer and +1. Dankie :)